# SCSS Absolute Saturation

Tags: sass

Out Designer gave us an instruction "This Color needs to be 8% of the 'Saturation' of the Primary Color" he means with it, the saturation is 8%. how can I do this in scss as I just can saturate or desaturate by an amount?

```
$saturation: saturation($primary);

// how can I calculate the amount?
$color1: saturate($primary, $amount);
$color2: desaturate($primary, $amount);
```

neither looks like it works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you referred to `saturate` in the Sass API? Are you using a percentage for the amount?

http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#saturate-instance_method